# BSoup against raw parsing in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, selector

My question is more of a generic one rather than single code based. I´m scraping some websites, and have been doing so with selenium+Bsoup4 (it´s javascript based).

Up until now I didn´t think of any other way, but browsing through threads I started to get in touch more with the elements suh as

```
element(by.id("id"));
element(by.css("#id"));
element(by.xpath("//*[@id='id']"))
```

So my question is, is it really necessary to get plain text and use `find_all` to locate the info you need when you can do the same with xpath or css? I mean, what is the difference in terms of coding?

And another one, in terms of speed, which way is faster? Or robust for all that matters.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: *"in terms of speed, which way is faster?"* Have you measured? If yes, why do you ask? If no, why not?

Comment: Beacause I don´t know how. And because if I don´t understand very well the difference between when or for what to use them,which is what I mainly asked,, is unlikely I am able to ascertain the difference in efficiency or speed.

Comment: If you're interested in seeing which one is fastest, search around for "python profiling" and feel free to ask a new question if you get stuck on it. However, I have a hunch that all of them are about the same speed and you're going to spend the _vast_ majority of your time downloading the page with Selenium.